# Why call the superclass method when you override the existing method?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to JAVA and OOP in general. In this very simple code, why I have to call the onCreate method from the superclass? isn't it inherited from the superclass? I know that a constructor method is not inherited to the child class and if you want to call the constructor you must invoke the superclass. Is super.onCreate a constructor call? Doesn't the constructor name must be the same with the class name ?
I know this is a silly question and thank you for your responses.

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why call *any* method? You call the methods you need to call. In this case, the spec says call it, so you call it. Not a real question.

Comment: Because you're calling the method on the super class **and** adding more behavior after that: `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: @EJP it is a real question for me because I don't have all the answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> why I have to call the onCreate method from the superclass? isn't it inherited from the superclass?

The implementation is inherited, but you're overriding it. You need to indicate that you don't just want to *replace* the original behaviour - you want to execute that behaviour from the superclass *and then* extra code.

This isn't a constructor call - unless you explicitly call the superclass implementation, its code simply won't be executed. Also unlike constructors, the superclass implementation call doesn't have to be the first statement of a method. You can call the superclass implementation wherever you like, even multiple times.

Here's a short but complete example program demonstrating the difference between calling a super method and not:

```
class Super {
    void method1() {
        System.out.println("Super.method1");
    }

    void method2() {
        System.out.println("Super.method2");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    @Override void method1() {
        // No explicit super call
        System.out.println("Sub.method1");
    }

    @Override void method2() {
        super.method2();
        System.out.println("Sub.method2");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Super x = new Sub();
        x.method1(); // Prints just Sub.method1
        x.method2(); // Prints Super.method2 and Sub.method2
    }    
}
```

(It would be entirely feasible for `Sub.method1` to call `super.method2()` by the way. You can call a superclass implementation of *any* method from the subclass.)

Answer (score 7):

Because that's how the android team designed the Activity. The Activity's `onCreate()` method does things that must be done for every activity created, and not calling `super.onCreate()` would bypass these mandatory things.

`onCreate()` is not a constructor. It's a method. If you override the method and don't call `super.onCreate()`, you redefine what the `onCreate()` method does. Calling `super.onCreate()` makes your `onCreate()` method do the same thing as the base `onCreate()` method, plus other things specific to your own activity.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29 for the documentation of this method.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see more than just words. Is starting to make sense.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I want to know: "Because that's how the android team designed the Activity."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the same method name so you are overriding the onCreate method from Activity. If you don't re-invoke that method in MainActivity it will just do setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with constructors, actually (besides, your statement about constructors not being called is not true in the case of default constructors).

The "OOP"-ish reason for doing so is that the `onCreate` method in the `Activity` class might contain certain code that *should* be called by the subclasses' implementation. You don't *have* to call it (as far as the Java language is concerned), though.

To know whether you should be calling the superclass' implementation of the method, you should consult with the documentation of the superclass' implementation. There's no right and wrong here; definitely a case-by-case thing.

Answer (score 1):

The method in the superclass is inherited, in the sense that it's available to subclasses, but it's not automatically called. In a subclass, you call the superclass's method so it can do whatever it does, then your method performs any additional work (just like in your example.

Here is a reference that will give you more information:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 1):

You override the super class method - as in you are replacing it. 
You have the option to call the super class method but you don t have to. It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. In some scenario you want to call the super class method because you need the logic of the subclass , perharps you are adding to it. In other cases you may want to replace the behavior entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The original `onCreate()` method is inherited yes, but that exact method isn't what this code does. This code wants the original method and it also needs to call `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. Instead of copying all of the code from the superclass here, it simply calls `super.onCreate()` and then adds the new stuff.